# AWS manage dependency between data pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, scheduling, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a situation in which I want to run a data pipeline (DP2) after the some other pipeline (DP1). In case DP1 hasn't finished successfully, I don't want DP2 to be run at all and if it is, I want DP2 to start running.
In fact, situation can become more and more complex in future, so I want to have an option to easily configure what runs when and in which order.

I just started looking at this and stumbled upon a solution that would include aws lambda looking at S3 and triggering DP2 in case DP1 produced a file in S3, for example.
This is ok-ish but I would rather go with something more robust.

Is there a tool that could do this kind of scheduling/ordering of data pipelines for me?

What came to my mind also is to build the tool using Jenkins as a foundation: create jenkins jobs (which relationships I can manage in Jenkins) and use them to trigger data pipelines on demand using [aws data pipeline api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) - basically, use Jenkins as a mechanism to fire commands to the pipeline api and check status of pipelines from time to time to see if they are running, got stuck, finished successfully and other...

This would take some time to build, of course, and that is why I am asking if there is already some tool I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing this has been to put a file in S3 at the successful completion of DP1, as  a last activity and then have DP2 have a Preconditon that checks for the existence of this file. This works if both your pipelines run on a fixed schedule.

Are your pipelines running on-demand in response to events?

Comment: Those pipelines are currently running on fixed schedule, let's say they start at 1AM meaning DP1 starts at 1AM and DP2 starts at 1.45AM, for example.

Comment: In that case, you should be able to use the precondition solution I mentioned.  If DP1 did not finish successfully, the objects from DP2 will go directly to FAILED state (i.e. without running) with the error reason being "Precondition not satisfied".

Answer (score 4):

I know its a bit late, but just found this.  You can trigger pipeline #2 from pipeline #1.

In Pipeline #1, include as the last activity a ShellCommandActivity that activates Pipeline #2 upon successful completion of Pipeline #1.
Command to execute: aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id #{myPipelineToActivateID} where myPipelineToActivateID is the Pipeline ID of Pipeline #2.

Pipeline #2 should be created as an "on demand" pipeline.  When it is initially set up, set the Schedule to run "on pipeline activation" instead of on a schedule.